# Sufficient condition for monotone likelihood ratio property

Tags: probability-distributions

What are sufficient conditions for the monotone likelihood ratio property?  I have a set-up where $F(x)$ (cumulative distribution function of r.v.
$x$) always exceeds $G(x)$ (a different cum. distrib. function), when these 
c.d.f.s are taken as functions with an argument of $x$?

Answer (score 0):

The relationship you're describing is stochastic dominance.  You need $f(x)/g(x)$ to be monotonic in $x$, where $f,g$ are the density functions corresponding to $F,G$ to get the MLRP.

Comment: Thanks.  I had it in mind that MLRP implies stochastic dominance, but not the other way around.

Comment: That sounds right.